# Android: stay connected with checkbox

Tags: android, authentication, logout, android-checkbox

I want to add a checkbox in login-phase that, when it is clicked the app remember the user also when he exits without logout, 
but when this checkbox isn't clicked the user access to several activities but when he exits without logout there is still the logout.
This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private EditText  username=null;
    private EditText  password=null;

    private Button login, registration;


    public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String user = "nameKey"; 
    public static final String pass = "passwordKey"; 


    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    public boolean isChecked = false;
    public boolean isunChecked = true;



    private CheckBox check;

    String a,b, result,z, clic;

    Class<?> activityClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        registration = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);


        login.setOnClickListener(this);
        registration.setOnClickListener(this);
        check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        check.setOnClickListener(this);


    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1 : {

            login.setEnabled(false);
            registra.setEnabled(true);
            registra.setClickable(false);
            username.setFocusable(false);
            password.setFocusable(false);


            if (check.isChecked()) {
                clic = "Checked";
                System.out.println("CheckBox is checked");
            }
            else{
                clic = "no_Checked";
                System.out.println("CheckBox is unchecked");
            }

            LoginTask task = new LoginTask(username,password);
            task.execute(null,null,null);


            break;
        }
        case R.id.button2: {

            registration.setEnabled(false);
            login.setEnabled(true);
            login.setClickable(false);

            registration(v);
            break;
        }



        }
    }



    public class LoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

        public LoginTask(EditText username2, EditText password2) {

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
                }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);



            if(result.equals("ok")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            else {

                login.setEnabled(true);
                login.setClickable(true);

                registration.setEnabled(true);
                registration.setClickable(true);


                username.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                password.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);

            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String result = null;
            Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();

            try {
                [....]

                String u = username.getText().toString();
                String p = password.getText().toString();


                editor.putString(user, u);
                editor.putString(pass, p);


                if(clic.equals("checked
                    editor.putBoolean("isChecked", isChecked);
                    System.out.println("clic");
                }else{
                    editor.putBoolean("isChecked", isunChecked);
                    System.out.println("no_clic");
                }


                editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);

                startActivity(intent);


            }

            catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();

                return result=e.getMessage();

            }
            return result="ok";

        }


    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, 
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);



        if(isChecked = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("isChecked", true)){

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (sharedpreferences.contains(user))
            {
                if(sharedpreferences.contains(pass)){

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "login", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    System.out.println("    CheckBox is checked");
                    try {
                        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("X", MODE_PRIVATE);

                        activityClass = Class.forName(prefs.getString("activity1", FirstActivity.class.getName()));
                        prefs.getString("activity2", SecondActivity.class.getName());


                    } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) {

                    }


                    Intent i = new Intent(this, activityClass);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            }

        }else{

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "logout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println("logout");
            //logout();

        }
        super.onResume();
    }



    public void registration (View view){

        Intent intent1;
        intent1 = new Intent (this, Registration.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }


    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        this.finish();
    }

    public void closing() {
        finish();
    }
```

this code doesn't work, because when the checkbox isn't checked the user is logged yet. maybe I'm wrong to place the control on the checkbox? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

your user is remebered because when you pause the app, all attributes hold active. you have to destroy the main activity launcher to delete these values To hold the session if you click checkbox I recommend you to use a data base where you remember the user, password and active.